# sitemap.xml shows different base path when generate

Tags: xml, seo, magento2.2.6, sitemaps

[image]I have generated the sitemap for my live instance. But after generating it 
it is showing staging url in xml sitemap.

When I see my xml sitemap in the browser for live site, it shows the links with staging URL...

is there any setting that i am missing

Comment: as I can see your `sitemap.xml`, all URLs are started by `https://www.zitomer.com/`. Can you point out any URL which is coming from staging site? what is your staging URL ?

Comment: please check i have addded scree shot

Comment: check my answer please @rk1990

Answer (score 1):

I think You need to clear your cache using command -

`rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/*`

as I have checked your `sitemap.xml`, it is showing correct URLs.

check this image --

[image]

Comment: Yes ... it is working ... but I have just simply deleted the xml file and regenerated it... 
Your answer is also perfect ... Thanks

Comment: cool..  you can accept it as answer if it helped you thanks :)

Comment: I have voted up